# how to replace part of tuple

Tags: replacement, tuples

I would like to replace all elements $1/2$ in tuples with $0$,
How should i do that 
I tried already this one :  `sel1 = ReplacePart[sel[[#]], 1/2 -> 0]`

The tuples are:

`tuples = Tuples[{1, -1/2, 1/2}, {Lan, Lan}];
sel = Select[tuples, Total[#, 2] == 14 &]`

Comment: Note that your question has little or nothing to do with tuples... but instead with *any* list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all instances of `1/2` in `sel`, you can use `ReplaceAll (/.)` as

```
sel /. (1/2 -> 0)
```